# How to use the pcapy library in python to capture UDP packet by the method pcapy.next()

Tags: python, udp, pcapy

I am using `cap.next()` to capture UDP packets. Once it starts receiving packets it never comes out even if no packet is coming. Please help me. I have given the code below

If I would be using .loop attribute I could use

```
p = pcapy.open_live(dev, 65536, 1, 1)
p.setfilter('udp and src host 169.254.18.15 and port 5001')

print("capturing data...")
dumper = p.dump_open('data_loop.txt')

p.loop(NUM_OF_packet_to_receive, handle_packet)
```

By the previous code I can apply filter and in the `p.loop`, I could specify the number of packets to be received.

But I have to use `p.next()` and apply filter and set timeout.
Can anybody help me to apply filter and set timeout.

(pcapy doc is not properly written, any assists are welcome.)
Right now, I filtering form the raw data by my own, not using pcapy filter.

Code:

```
import time
import socket
from struct import *
import datetime
import pcapy
import sys

def getInterface():
    ifs = pcapy.findalldevs()
    if len(ifs) == 0:
        print("you don't have enough permission to open any interface")
        sys.exit(1)
    elif len(ifs) == 1:
        print("only one interface present, defaulting to it")
        return ifs[0]
    count = 0
    for iface in ifs:
        print(count, ": ", iface)
        count += 1
    idx = int(input('Please select an interface: '))
    return ifs[idx]

dev = getInterface()
index = 0
cap = pcapy.open_live(dev,
                      65536,  # to ensure capturing all of the
                      1,  # promiscious mode on
                      0)  # time out
print("Listening on %s: net=%s, mask=%s, linktype=%d" % (dev, cap.getnet(),
                                                         cap.getmask(),
                                                         cap.datalink()))
print("capturing data...")
dumper = cap.dump_open('data_p.txt')
while True:
    (header, packet) = cap.next()
    if ((len(packet) == 542) and
            (packet[26] == 169) and
            (packet[27] == 254) and
            (packet[29] == 15)):
        index += 1
        print(index)
```